# A sudden drop in free disk space

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage, partitioning

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. Today I suddenly started to get "low disk space" warnings. When I checked, I saw that free space on my Ubuntu partition is decreased like 2 or 3 gigabytes. I didn't install anything recently and I don't keep my files in my Ubuntu partition.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you do anything out of the ordinary before this started to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this to be a problem for me caused by log files building up.

`logrotate` is run as part of `cron.daily` which by default runs at 6:25 which is quite possible that your machine is never on at this time.

So I would start by checking `/var/log` disk usage.

If it is that, you can fix it by editing `/etc/crontab` and changing it to run `cron.daily` at 9:25 instead (or a time you know your machine is often on).

There is an application called "Disk Usage Analyser" installed by default. Use that on the whole filesystem.

Comment: "logrotate is run as part of cron.daily which by default runs at 6:25" - I think this is not true on a standard Ubuntu installation as it uses `anacron` to run cron scripts.

Comment: You are right it does. And as I understand it if the machine is off when a cron job was due to run, it will run it later. However I found that log files were not being rotated. This may be to the usage of this system which was on a 4GB USB stick used for short periods (<10mins) at a time. I would delete this answer if wrong but think it may help someone who experiences the same issue I had. I'll leave it posted for now until I get time to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after a while when I checked, it was OK, I don't know how, but my free space came back.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a number of things (internet caches, caches for other files, a runaway process storing data, etc.).

You can install [Baobab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab) (if it's not already installed) and use it to find out where most of your disk space is being used up.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, a buggy program started spamming error messages to stdout/stderr. These get logged to `~/.xsession-errors` and `~/.xsession-errors.old`, which can quickly fill several gigabytes of space [Bug 60448](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/60448).

A temporary fix is to truncate the file, by running `> ~/.xsession-errors` and `> ~/.xsession-errors.old`. (Deleting won't work, since the file is kept open.)

See also [How do I  prevent .xsession-errors from eating disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93718/how-do-i-prevent-xsession-errors-from-eating-disk-space).

Answer (score 1):

Press `ctrl + h` to show all your hidden folders. Look for .Trash1000. If such a folder exists, clear the files in it to get some space. You can also try clearing your trash and ~/.local/share/trash